# Spellcheck each line

Tags: bash, scripting, aspell

I'd like to write a bash filter that will take a file of newline-separated sentences and return sentences that are not misspelled. I've been thinking about aspell but I'm not sure what to do with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pipe should give the results you want. Note that you should pipe something into this, so prepend e.g. `cat input.txt |` for a quick test.

```
while read line; do [ "$(ispell -l <<< "$line" | wc -l)" -gt 0 ] && echo "$line"; done
```

To also prepend a line number:

```
nl -b a -p | while read number line; do [ "$(ispell -l <<< "$line" | wc -l)" -gt 0 ] && echo "$number: $line"; done
```

If you want to return misspelled lines instead, just replace `-gt` by `-le` (or replace `&&` by `||`, of course)

---

Of course you can save these lines as a script, and then simply do

```
script.sh < input.txt
```

if you so prefer

Comment: fixed a problem with my initial post (3min back) and shortened the commands

Comment: As always: For two hours and a half one no answer, and then two (quite similar) answers in five minutes.

Comment: I think it is a property of the type of question. I guess there are the 10-second questions, the 30-minute questions, the 2.5-hour questions and the 1 week questions (the others get closed). It is like an `Eigenfrequenz` of questions :_)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script which does what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Regex for lines describing "good words":
# - empty lines (after each line of input, i.e. at the end)
# - lines with only a '*' (indicating a good word)
# - a line with '@(#) '   (at the start of the output)
# All other lines indicate a bad word.
good_words='^[*]?$|^@\(#\) '

while read # read one line of input
do
    echo $REPLY | # pipe the line to aspell
    aspell pipe | # let aspell check the line
    egrep -q -v $good_words || # have a look if aspell found misspellings
    # no words with mistake, output the line
    echo $REPLY
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v "$(aspell list < file)" file
```